# Getting a picture in Facebook post API PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api

At the moment i'm busy with an automated system to post posts on my Facebook page (not personal profile, but business page).

I got stuck at the moment whre a picture needs to be post, i dont know where it goes wrong.

Code:

```
$publish = $fb->api('/page-id/feed', 'post',
    array(
    'access_token' => 'token',
    'message'=> "WEEKACTIE!
                 De vorige weekactie is geëindigd, maar de volgende weekactie staat klaar!

                 Met deze week: " . $desc . " voor maar € " . $get->price . " !

                 Deze actie geldt van " . date('j F Y', strtotime($week->week)) . " t/m " . date('j F Y',strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($week->week))) . "! 


                 Let op! Deze actie geldt alleen via onze eigen website of app!


                 ".$extras,
    'from' => '891001074264288',
    'to' => '275160489341953',
    'caption' => 'SNEEK.CHICKENBUTLER.NL',
    'name' => "WEEKACTIE: " . $get->name,
    'link' => 'https://sneek.chickenbutler.nl/',
    'picture' => 'https://teamarcade.gg/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/850x850-web.png',
    'description' => "WEEKACTIE!
                      De vorige weekactie is geëindigd, maar de volgende weekactie staat klaar!
                      Met deze week: " . $desc . " voor maar € " . $get->price . " !

                      Deze actie geldt van " . date('j F Y', strtotime($week->week)) . " t/m " . date('j F Y',strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($week->week))) . "! 
                      ".$extras." 

                      Let op! Deze actie geldt alleen via onze eigen website of app!"
    ));
```

Comment: Well, what happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, it just placed everything on Facebook, except the picture. @ceejayoz

Comment: What API version are you using? Read the note on "Custom Link Page Post Image" at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed - "As of November 7, 2017, link customization is available however the link must be owned by the posting page and a page access token is required."

Comment: That was it thanks !

Comment: OK, I'll make that an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed:

> As of November 7, 2017, link customization is available however the link must be owned by the posting page and a page access token is required. To verify ownership, check the ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts} field on the URL node. You must call this endpoint before posting new links. Without this step, custom link page posts will not work for un-scraped links. See our Link Ownership Guide for more information. For versions 2.10 and lower, picture, name, thumbnail, and description are deprecated. caption is deprecated for all versions.